# Traces inequalities for projectors and reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Let $V$ - finite dimension space, $A : V \to V$ positive semidefinite operator, $P$ - orthoprojector ($P^2 = P = P^*$) $R$ - reflection ($R^2 = 1$, $R^* = R$).

Can we say something nontrivial (any inequalities, e.g) about $\operatorname{Tr}[PA]$ or $\operatorname{Tr}[RA]$?

Comment: What does $1$ mean in $T^2=1$, is that the identity operator? Also, what is $R$ in Tr$[RA]$

Comment: Yes. I fix it. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can indeed say that 
$$
|\operatorname{Tr}[PA]| \leq \operatorname{Tr}[A]
$$
The same **cannot** be said for $R$.  We do have, however,
$$
|\operatorname{Tr}[RA]| \leq \|R\| \operatorname{Tr}[A]
$$
Where $\|R\|^2$ is the largest eigenvalue of $R^*R$.

---

Another interesting result in the case of $P$ is that we can say
$$
|\operatorname{Tr}[PA]| \leq \sqrt{\operatorname{rank}(P)\operatorname{Tr}[A^*A]}
$$
since $\operatorname{Tr}(P) = \operatorname{rank}(P)$.  We also have
$$
|\operatorname{Tr}[PA]| \leq \operatorname{rank}(P)\|A\|
$$
with $\|\cdot\|$ as defined above.